# for ... in - Is the object being iterated evaluated just once before entering the loop?

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

When I use a for ... in loop like:

```
for(var i in object) {}
```

I want to know if the `object` in question is evaluated just once or each time the loop, well, *loops*.

I made a quick test in my browser (also in node) like:

```
for(var i in (console.log('INIT'), [1, 2, 3, 4])) { console.log('KEY', i); }
```

and I get:

```
INIT
KEY 0
KEY 1
KEY 2
KEY 3
```

So from this empirical evidence, I could assume that is indeed only evaluated once.

But, is this behavior standard?

Comment: I'd have to read the standard, but it would be extremely surprising if this wasn't so -- you don't want a function that returns an iterable object to be called on each iteration! The object being iterated could change partway through the loop, otherwise.

Comment: [The expression on the right-hand side of `in` is evaluated once.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4)

Answer (score 3):

From the Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), a `for...in` loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype.  An (enumerable) property that is deleted before it has been visited will not be visited later. Properties added to the object over which iteration is occurring may either be visited or omitted from iteration.

In short, the outcome of the example posted by @Amit is not guaranteed, although Chrome and IE may use a different specification for the `for ..in` loop. However, at least deleting an element seems to prevent it from being visited in Chrome:

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for(var k in obj) {
  document.write(k);
  delete obj['c']; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that `(console.log('INIT'), [1, 2, 3, 4])` is an expression that evaluates to `[1, 2, 3, 4]` so it's not a valid evidence of the issue. A better empirical evidence can be obtained with:

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for(var k in obj) {
  document.write(k);
  obj.d = 4;
}
```

And we don't see "d"...

Comment: This example (1) does not answer the question of whether "the object in question is evaluated just once" (because in your example, it could be evaluated every time), and (2) shows behaviour which is explicitly left open by the ECMAscript standard (whether keys added during the iteration will subsequently be iterated or not).

Comment: @rici - this is probably as close as possible to empirical proof of current behavior, and it corrects the code fragment from OP,so your "1" point is wrong. As for 2, I *obviously* wasn't trying to address the standard, so I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: @amit: because you misinterpret the question, you assume the OP's code fragment was incorrect. OP is asking if "the object in question is evaluated just once". They are not asking anything about the enumeration order of the object's properties. Their code fragment was designed to show whether the object is evaluated on every loop, and it indicates that the object is only evaluated once, which is what the standard specifies. Your code fragment is designed to test whether items added to the object during the iteration are enumerated as part of the iteration, which the standard does not specify.

Comment: @rici - perhaps *you* misunderstand, but `(console.log('INIT'), [1, 2, 3, 4])` is an **expression**. It evaluates to an array. There's no reason whatsoever for the log to happen twice **regardless** of the semantics of `for..in`. *My* code does show an "as close as possible" (or at least as close as I could come up with so far, feel free to improve on that) evidence of the semantics by way of showing that when an object "grows" during iteration, the new properties are left unnoticed by the iteration operation - perhaps because the object is "only evaluated once".

Comment: @Amit: Until OP intervenes, we'll have to agree to differ. I understand that the expression is an expression, and that seems to me 100% consistent with the question as to whether the expression will be evaluated more than once. OP asks whether the **expression** will be evaluated more than once; proposes an experiment to test whether the **expression** is evaluated more than once, finds that it is evaluated once, and asks if that is guaranteed. The most natural explanation of the question is to take it literally, IMHO.

Comment: @rici - I can definitely agree to disagree, but I don't think that's what the question is about. The term used (several times) is "object", not "expression". I'm certain it's obvious to all (including OP) that `for x in f()` will call function `f()` exactly one time. What was not obvious to OP is that the comma operator is not an object generator and that the parenthesis enclosed statements form a single expression that's evaluated only once. It returns an object (just like `f()` does) and the question is how this object is treated.

Answer (score 0):

The [ECMAScript® Language Specification, section 12.6.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4) does not say much about this, except that the expression on the right side is evaluated once and cast to an object:

> 1. Let *exprRef* be the result of evaluating the *Expression*.
> 2. Let *experValue* be GetValue(*exprRef*).
> 3. If *experValue* is `null` or `undefined`, return (normal, empty, empty).
> 4. Let *obj* be ToObject(*experValue*).

This says nothing about evaluating any of the keys or values of that object at that time.

In fact, the part that follows the quoted paragraph suggests the keys could be retrieved during the iterations:

> 6. Repeat
>
>    - Let *P* be the name of the next property of *obj* whose [[Enumerable]] attribute is `true`. If there is no such property, return (normal, *V*, empty).

But there is no requirement in either direction. So, ... this could be implementation (browser) dependent.

When you say that the *object is evaluated just once*, that can be have different meanings:

1. The object *reference* is evaluated just once. This is important when that object is the outcome of an expression, such as a function call. But this is surely taken for granted and not what you mean;
2. The object's *keys* (properties) are enumerated once, but the values are retrieved on demand;
3. The object's *keys and values* are retrieved once. This could be done at 1 level or nested levels at a potential high memory cost.

This test case shows in my browser (FireFox) the second happens, not the third:

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
for (key in obj) {
    document.write('obj[' + key + '] = ' + obj[key] + '<br>');
    if (key=='a') {
        // modify a value that is still to be visited
        obj["c"] = 4;
        // add a key/value pair
        obj["d"] = 9;
    }
}
```

Output is (as you can probably also see in your browser):

> obj[a] = 1
>   obj[b] = 2
>   obj[c] = 4

So the keys were only retrieved once, the values on demand (i.e. not at the start of the loop).